# How to test 404 error with watir-webdriver in cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, http-status-code-404, watir-webdriver

How can I test the 404 errors (page not found) in cucumber? I have for example a page with 100 pictures and I want to test if all of the pictures are visible. I want to check if one or more of the pictures have 404 error or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "apod.nasa.gov/"
b.execute_script("return (typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth!=\"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth>0)", b.image(name: 'imagename1'))
```

See [this blog post](http://watirmelon.com/2012/11/27/checking-an-image-is-actually-visible-using-webdriver/) for more info

Comment: Thx, but this is not what I need. I dont want to describe every picture, I just want to check are all pictures present on the page or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you harvest the image urls (using watir, [nokigiri](http://nokogiri.org/), or [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/)), you can use [open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) to issue requests and then check the response code.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require "open-uri" 

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "http://www.iana.org/domains/special"

urls = b.images.collect(&:src)               # harvest image srcs
urls << "http://www.foo.com/foo.gif"         # example of a 500 error

urls.each do |url|
  begin
    open(url) do |f|
      puts "#{f.base_uri} - #{f.status}"
    end
  rescue => e
    puts "#{url} - #{e}"
  end
end
```